Apple Store Server Notification takes too long on Sandbox environment
This is my first time using Apple’s In-App Purchase (IAP).
Currently, it takes 30 to 45 seconds for my server to receive notifications in the sandbox environment.
Is it the same in the production environment?
Has anyone experienced this before?
Is there any way to test in the production environment before making a release?
I would like to know how long it takes to receive Apple Store server notifications in the production environment.
Is there any way to make a real in-app purchase before releasing the app?
